# python unittest - assert any raise

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have some codes structured in this way:

```
Method(args):
    try:
          {method}
          if "ok": return True 
          else: return False
      except:
          raise
```

And I have at least 3 unit tests to perform on this method, one to assert an ideal True condition, at least one where I expect Method to return False, and I wish to build a test that returns "ok" when any exception/error is raised.

I know about assertRaise already, but it asks for a specific exception, and I wish to assert any condition raised as true.

Comment: What is the point of a blank `try/except` (catch any exception) with only `raise` (reraise same exception and do nothing) in the except block? Just remove the try/except block entirely...

Comment: You don't _have_ to use assertRaises.  You can just do an explicit try/catch in the test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are essentially catching every exception type, your `assertRaises` should expect the most basic exception type, which is `Exception`.

```
assertRaises(Exception, Method)
```

Comment: I tried this already... this unit test returns as an Error and, as I'm testing for exceptions, I wish this test to pass...

Comment: @BrunoLaget It's not really clear. Do you want the test to pass if an exception occurs? This is what `assertRaises` does.

Comment: you are right, I just corrected a syntax error and the test passed just as I needed. Thanks a lot!